# How to set up in Mac to access R from Weka

Tags: weka

I tried to follow the instruction [here](https://weka.waikato.ac.nz/advanceddataminingwithweka/forum) to set up weka for using R, but I could not get things to work.

If you read all the posts in the link above, I located my problem at the failure of setting R_HOME in Mac.

For some reason, I just could not get R_HOME set right.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got this to work with the following steps:

The easy one has already specified in the post link in the question:

1. replace the old info.Plist with [the new one](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5yvejrCQ2QSVnZHWUVGRXhZMVU) given by Mark Hall
2. install R from [here](https://www.r-project.org/)
3. install `Rplugin` with `Weka Package Manager`
4. install `rJava` inside R with `install.packages('rJava')`
5. get the path of R_HOME by running `R.home(component = "home")` in R
6. if you want to specify which library directory to be used (but as R updates, version number of the path will change as well, thanks to Michael Hall, see this disucssion below), then get the path of R_LIBS_USER by running `.libPaths()` in R

The steps which troubled me for a while:

7. in terminal, run `nano .bash_profile`, at the top paste the following two lines of code

   function wekastart() {

   ```
   export Weka_Data=/Users/Natsume/Documents/istep/wekaData
   export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources

   java -Xss10M -Xmx4096M -cp :weka.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser
   ```

   }

the R_HOME paths is what you get from R codes above; Weka_Data path is where you store your dataset for weka.

8. press `ctrl x` and `enter` to save and exit
9. run `source .bash_profile` to activate, then run `echo $R_HOME` and `echo $R_LIBS_USER` to verify. If it returns the paths, then you did it

Every time when to start Weka with R, go to the directory where `weka.jar` is at, just run `wekastart` in terminal.

---

### A short and easy solution suggested by Michael Hall

1. After completing the 1-4 steps listed above, then
2. go to weka 3-8-0 folder, and open its terminal, and
3. run the following 2 lines of codes

   export R_HOME=/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
   java -Xss10M -Xmx4096M -cp .:weka.jar weka.gui.GUIChooser
4. to make life easier, inside a directory where you want to work with weka, save the code above into a file named as `weka_r.sh`
5. make it executable, inside this directory's terminal, run the code below:

   chmod a+x weka_r.sh
6. paste `weka.jar` from weka 3-8-0 into the directory and run the code below:

   ./weka_r.sh

Now, you are ready to go. Next time, you just need to go to the directory's terminal and run `./weka_r.sh` to start R with Weka.